# How to scale gradients in a gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: optimization, scaling, neural-network

I am training a neural network with the multiobjective steepest gradient descent algorithm. The want to steer the direction of the gradient descent so that I land up at a point slightly above where I am landing now. How can I achieve this? Is there any mathematical way to scale the gradients? In case of the neural networks, I am only minimizing the loss function. I am trying to steer the direction of gradient descent by adding some random weights or biases to the loss. How can I mathematically scale the gradients to steer the direction?

Comment: Do you want to change the gradient direction? Or just over- or undershoot the minimum in the selected fixed direction? Note that in NN training a descent direction is almost never established, in a single step you reduce a single term of the residual sum, but that may well increase other terms. The hope is that on average over many steps a descent happens in all terms.

Comment: Sounds like you are kind of asking for a Line Search method, which leads to the excellent answers given in: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321592/are-line-search-methods-used-in-deep-learning-why-not

Comment: @LutzLehmann - Yes thats true but still we can achieve a descent over a period of time(several epochs) like we do gradient descent on a single loss function. But don't we follow any descent direction? Eventually we succeed in getting a descent correct over several epochs but does that deviate from the steepest descent direction?